# Dynamic Programming for analyzing a Vector of Vector of Bools

Tags: c++, dynamic, vector

Here's the problem I'm trying to solve.

Given a square of bools, I want to find the size of largest subsquare entirely full of trues (1's).  Also, I am allowed O(n^2) memory requirement as well as the run time must be O(n^2). The header to the function will look like the following

```
 unsigned int largestCluster(const vector<vector<bool>> &map);
```

Some other things to note will be there always be at least one 1 (a 1 x 1 subsquare) and the input will also always be a square.

Now for my attempts at the problem:
Given this is based on the concept of dynamic programming, which to my limited understanding, helps store information that is previously found for later use.  So if my understanding is correcting, Prim's algorithm would be an example of a dynamic algorithm because it remembers what vertices we've visited, the smallest distance to a vertice, and the parent that enables that smallest distance.

I tried analyzing the map and keeping track of the number of true neighbors, a true location location has.  I was thinking if a spot had 4 true neighbors than that is a potential subsquare.  However, this didn't help with subsquares of size 4 or less..

I tried to include a lot of detail in this question for help as I'm trying to game plan a way to tackle this problem because I don't believe it's going to require writing a lengthy function. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my nomination. Dynamic programming, O(n^2) complexity. I realize that I probably just did somebody's homework, but it looked like an intriguing little problem.

```
int largestCluster(const std::vector<std::vector<bool> > a)
{
    const int n = a.size();
    std::vector<std::vector<short> > s;
    s.resize(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        s[i].resize(n);
    }

    s[0][0] = a[0][0] ? 1 : 0;
    int maxSize = s[0][0];

    for (int k = 1; k < n; ++k)
    {
        s[k][0] = a[k][0] ? 1 : 0;
        for (int j = 1; j < k; ++j)
        {
            if (a[k][j])
            {
                int m = s[k - 1][j - 1];
                if (s[k][j - 1] < m)
                {
                    m = s[k][j - 1];
                }
                if (s[k - 1][j] < m)
                {
                    m = s[k - 1][j];
                }
                s[k][j] = ++m;

                if (m > maxSize)
                {
                    maxSize = m;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                s[k][j] = 0;
            }
        }

        s[0][k] = a[0][k] ? 1 : 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= k; ++i)
        {
            if (a[i][k])
            {
                int m = s[i - 1][k - 1];
                if (s[i - 1][k] < m)
                {
                    m = s[i - 1][k];
                }
                if (s[i][k - 1] < m)
                {
                    m = s[i][k - 1];
                }
                s[i][k] = ++m;

                if (m > maxSize)
                {
                    maxSize = m;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                s[i][k] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    return maxSize;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a dynamic programming approach one strategy I could think of would be to consider a box (base case 1 entry) as a potential upper left corner of a larger box and start by the bottom right corner of your large square, you then need to evaluate only the "boxes" (using information previously stored to only consider the largest cluster so far) that are to the right, bottom, and diagonally right-bottom of that we are now evaluating.
By saving information about each edge we would be respecting the O(n^2) (though not o(n^2)) however for the run-time you need to work on the details of the approach to get to O(n^2)

This is just a rough draft idea as I don't have much time, and I would appreciate any more hints/comments about this myself.

Comment: My thoughts are going in a similar direction, but I'll also need more time to make sure that it holds up. I was going to describe it in more detail here, but ran out of comment space. I'll post it as an answer if I still think it will work after thinking about it more over the next 1-2 days. Fun problem.